# Pop up images on the page every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page function that shows and hides images every 5 seconds.

Instead of these two images, I need to open random images from the list each time.

I added an array with images, tried to add the creation of an image in the popup() function, and the removal of the hidePopup() function, but nothing happened.

```js
var images = new Array("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/304/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/508/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/70B/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/90F/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/AA0/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/CB0/fff",
    "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/EC0/fff");

var randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

popup();

function popup() {

  document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(hidePopup, 5000);

}

function hidePopup() {

  document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(popup, 5000);

}
```

```html
<div id="disclaimer">
<div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff"></div>
<div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/304/fff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(hidePopup, 5000);` needs to be `setTimeout(hidePopup(), 5000);`

Comment: Conversely .. `setTimeout(popup, 5000);` also needs to be `setTimeout(popup(), 5000);`

Comment: The only problem I found was that the array was `[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];`, not `images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the HTML file you should create a div with an id disclaimer

```
<div id="disclaimer"></div>
```

- Then in the js file you should select the HTML element out of the popup function

```
const el =  document.getElementById("disclaimer");
```

- And create an enter code hereimage element out of the popup function

```
const img = document.createElement('img')
```

- Then in the popup function you should create a random image every time the function get called with setTimeout to change the image src, set attribute src for image with random image number from images array, and append an image element to the div in HTML file
  and call setTimeout with hidepop

```
function popup() {
  randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)
  img.setAttribute('src', images[randomImage])
  img.setAttribute('alt', 'random')
  el.appendChild(img);
  setTimeout(hidePopup, 1000);
}
```

- Then create a hidepop()

```
function hidePopup() {
  setTimeout(popup, 1000);
}
```

- And call popup function

```
popup()
```

**Note** :
In setTimeout function don't call the handler like that

```
setTimeout(hidePopup(), 1000);
```

that will cause  Maximum call stack size exceeded error and you app will crashed

Answer (score 0):

Set a promise then change the image randomly every N milliseconds.

```js
const images = ["http://dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/304/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/508/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/70B/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/90F/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/AA0/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/CB0/fff",
  "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/EC0/fff"
];
const id = "disclaimer";
const imageElement = document.getElementById(id);

function wait(ms, value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}

function getRandomImageIndex() {
  let randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  return randomImageIndex;
}

function setImage() {
  let index = getRandomImageIndex();
  var w = wait(5000, index);
  w.then(function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    imageElement.setAttribute('src', images[index]);
  }).then(function() {
    imageElement.classList.toggle('hide-me');
    return wait(5000, 1);
  }).then(function() {
    imageElement.classList.toggle('hide-me');
    setImage();
  });
}
// start it off
setImage();
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="disclaimer">
  <div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff" alt="howdy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the show/hide by toggling a class but just changing the image might also work?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to change the source of the image.

```js
var images = new Array("//dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/304/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/508/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/70B/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/90F/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/AA0/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/CB0/fff",
    "//dummyimage.com/100x100/EC0/fff");

popup();

function popup() {

  randomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];

  document.getElementById("changeThis").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("changeThis").src = randomImage;
  setTimeout(hidePopup, 5000);

}

function hidePopup() {

  document.getElementById("changeThis").style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(popup, 5000);

}
```

```html
<img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100/100/fff" id="changeThis">
```

If you would prefer to not have the images disappear, you can remove `style.display = "none";`, and replace `setTimeout(popup, 5000);` with `popup();`

**You should replace `//` with `https://` or `http://` if this is being accessed as a file.**